# java.time: Does the CET time zone considers daylight saving time?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I use the new `java.time` implementation of Java 8 and wonder about the output of a UTC to [CET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) time conversion result.

```
ZonedDateTime utcTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 7, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime cetTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(utcTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("CET"));
System.out.println("Summer-UTC-Time: " + utcTime);
System.out.println("Summer-CET-Time: " + cetTime);

System.out.println();

utcTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
cetTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(utcTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("CET"));
System.out.println("Winter-UTC-Time: " + utcTime);
System.out.println("Winter-CET-Time: " + cetTime);
```

I expected that the CET time would always be +1 of the UTC time but instead I got:

```
Summer-UTC-Time: 2014-07-01T08:00Z[UTC]
Summer-CET-Time: 2014-07-01T10:00+02:00[CET] -> +2 **Unexpected**

Winter-UTC-Time: 2014-01-01T08:00Z[UTC]
Winter-CET-Time: 2014-01-01T09:00+01:00[CET] -> +1 Expected
```

So apparently I have to deal with daylight saving time which I did not expect when using CET. Is the `java.time` CET in truth [CEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time)? And if yes, what zone should I use if I need CET?

Comment: `CET` is not identical to `UTC+1`, at least, how the IANA time zone database defines it. And this is what Java, POSIX and several database vendors use.

Comment: @Holger Your comment 'CET is not identical to UTC+1' seems to be the most correct answer - although the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) reference documents a fixed UTC offset of +1 (+2 would be CEST in regions with DST). I did a quick look at IANA but that did not helped me to understand their definition. Nevertheless if you add your comment as answer (maybe providing some more background information) I would accept it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [IANA definition of CET](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) is that it follows the time-zone rules of Central Europe, which includes both winter and summer time. The rules can be seen [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/europe#L627), which shows that "CET" is based on ["C-Eur"](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/europe#L564) which includes summer time.

In `java.time` you can also see the full set of rules:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("CET");
System.out.println(zone);
System.out.println(zone.getRules());
for (ZoneOffsetTransition trans : zone.getRules().getTransitions()) {
  System.out.println(trans);
}
for (ZoneOffsetTransitionRule rule : zone.getRules().getTransitionRules()) {
  System.out.println(rule);
}
```

which prints:

```
CET
ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1916-04-30T23:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1916-10-01T01:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1917-04-16T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1917-09-17T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1918-04-15T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1918-09-16T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1940-04-01T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1942-11-02T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1943-03-29T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1943-10-04T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1944-04-03T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1944-10-02T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1945-04-02T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1945-09-16T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1977-04-03T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1977-09-25T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1978-04-02T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1978-10-01T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1979-04-01T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1979-09-30T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1980-04-06T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1980-09-28T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1981-03-29T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1981-09-27T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1982-03-28T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1982-09-26T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1983-03-27T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1983-09-25T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1984-03-25T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1984-09-30T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1985-03-31T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1985-09-29T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1986-03-30T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1986-09-28T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1987-03-29T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1987-09-27T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1988-03-27T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1988-09-25T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1989-03-26T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1989-09-24T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1990-03-25T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1990-09-30T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1991-03-31T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1991-09-29T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1992-03-29T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1992-09-27T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1993-03-28T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1993-09-26T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1994-03-27T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1994-09-25T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1995-03-26T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1995-09-24T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1996-03-31T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1996-10-27T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
Transition[Gap at 1997-03-30T02:00+01:00 to +02:00]
Transition[Overlap at 1997-10-26T03:00+02:00 to +01:00]
TransitionRule[Gap +01:00 to +02:00, SUNDAY on or after MARCH 25 at 02:00 STANDARD, standard offset +01:00]
TransitionRule[Overlap +02:00 to +01:00, SUNDAY on or after OCTOBER 25 at 02:00 STANDARD, standard offset +01:00]
```

The key here is to understand that the time-zone identifier and the ["short name"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) of that identifier are two different elements. The identifier is always fixed as "CET", but the name changes between "CET" and "CEST".

Comment: Still confusing for me that it is somehow different than the usual explanation of CET that can be found outside IANA (e.g. wikipedia) but certainly the best - and correct - answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you know the offset and don't want to use DTS, why not use `ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)` method instead of `ZoneId.of("CET")`?

<del>Also you can call `normalized()` on any ZoneId instance to make it a fixed offset but sounds like less reliable than using an offset from the beginning.</del>

From [ZoneId javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html):

> A ZoneId is used to identify the rules used to convert between an
>   Instant and a LocalDateTime. There are two distinct types of ID:
>
> - Fixed offsets - a fully resolved offset from UTC/Greenwich, that uses the same offset for all local date-times
> - Geographical regions - an area where a specific set of rules for finding the offset from UTC/Greenwich apply
>
> Most fixed offsets are represented by ZoneOffset. Calling normalized()
>   on any ZoneId will ensure that a fixed offset ID will be represented
>   as a ZoneOffset.

If you're not using fixed offsets, then you're using geographical regions which means it depends on the region if DTS is observed or not. Same goes with PST. You'll see it observes DTS even though summer time is called PDT. Yes, it is confusing but this is how most tools work. Read the full [ZoneId javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) for a more thorough explanation (the `Time-zone IDs` section).

Comment: I need to read a date value from a database that I consider to be in CET. I thought using the TimeZone and the corresponding rules would handle offsets and daylight saving (if relevant) for me.

Comment: @FrVaBe, it should handle it. Read http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet . You'll see that zone covers regions that do observer DTS. There are regions with same time zone but without DTS which are written as +1. Do you think the system storing the values to DB is using CET for areas that are actually +1? btw that's one of the reasons to always store UTC to DB. The other is that at times local time with DTS cannot be unambiguously converted to UTC.

Comment: I just thought - as stated in the link you provided - CET is always UTC+1 - otherwise it would be CEST. In this case CET would be as good as UTC. Conversion between both would be simple but now I observe that DST matters in CET and I wonder why. My simple question could be: Why is CET not always UTC+1 when using java.time?

Comment: @FrVaBe, updated my answer. Basically I think what you ask can be found in ZoneId javadoc. i.e. geographical region vs fixed timezone.

Comment: You can’t use `normalized()` for this task. `normalized()` will return an offset-based `ZoneID` *if and only if* the `ZoneID` on which you call it has a fixed offset as well, otherwise the `ZoneID` is returned unchanged. Or in other words, the underlying `ZoneRules` and hence the overall result regarding this question don’t change when using a `normalized()` `ZoneID`.