# Get CET winter time in Java

Tags: java, time

I have the following code to print the time in ISO8601:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("CET");
ZoneOffset zoneOffSet = zone.getRules().getOffset(now);

System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(zoneOffSet).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
```

However, this always print the summer time (UTC+1) and not UTC+2 while we are in winter. How could I change this to print the time according to the season?

Comment: Don't use three-letter time zone IDs. Use the full IANA name, e.g. `Europe/Paris`, `Europe/Berlin` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mistaken?

```
CET  = Central European Time         = UTC + 1  = Winter time
CEST = Central European Summer Time  = UTC + 2  = Summer Time
```

Also, from this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27618073/461499

> The key here is to understand that the time-zone **identifier** and the
>   "**short name**" of that identifier **are two different elements**. The
>   identifier is always fixed as "CET", but the name changes between
>   "CET" and "CEST".

Comment: So I need to do an `if` loop to manually change from `CET` to `CEST` based on the date?

Comment: No. Just set the zone to `CET` (or better, something like `Europe/Paris`). Java will figure out if it is summertime or wintertime for you, based on the given date and the `ZoneOffsetTransitionRule`s that are in your `ZoneId#getRules().getTransitionRules()`

Answer (score 0):

CET standard time is UTC+1

It is UTC+2 when daylight saving time (summer)

So it is correct that you get UTC+1